# Download content from url store in a text area

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to download content from an url and insert it into my database. I have already downloaded it, but it is displayed in a single line in the text area. I want it to display like a paragraph (wrapped if necessary) in the text area. Here is what I have tried:

```
String x="";


try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mirroreddatabase", "root", "");
    String data=cmbGeneNames.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String sql="select * from  omimmirrored where symbolGeneSymbol LIKE  '%"+data+"%'";//change table

    PreparedStatement   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet  rs=pst.executeQuery();

    //which checkboxes are checked
    while ((rs.next())) {
        x = rs.getString("links");      
    }
    conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}

URL u;
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream dis;
String s;

try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mirroreddatabase", "root", "");
    String data=cmbGeneNames.getSelectedItem().toString();
    u = new URL(x);

    is = u.openStream();         

    dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    while ((s = dis.readLine())!= null) {


    //try {

    String sql = "update omimmirrored set sequence=? where symbolGeneSymbol LIKE '%"+data+"%'";
    PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
    statement.setString(1, s);

    statement.executeUpdate();

        //which checkboxes are checked
        //conn.close();
    //}
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

} finally {

    try {
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }
    try {  

        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException) {     
    } // end of 'finally' clause      
}
```

Comment: What are you fetching? html page?

Comment: yes html page but the contents are being stored in one line and i want it to be stored like a paragraph.

Comment: you should pay more attention to code formatting and make sure to have something in the catch clauses - at least logging

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can try to use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class from package NIO for example you can read the file as its original like this :

```
int amount = 0; // return The number of bytes read,
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
while(amount != -1){
    amount = source.read(buf); // source is your Input Stream, here source is object of type FileChannel
    buf.rewind(); // Rewinds this buffer. The position is set to zero and the mark is discarded
    if(amount != -1){
        for(int i =  0 ; i < amount ; i++)
            System.out.print((char)buf.get(i));
        }
    }
```